# AS3 Textfield Whitelisting

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

So I have this chatting application that only allows users to say specific words in an array (whitelisting). I really need some help creating a function to check each word, and replace those with "###" that are not in the whitelist. I have an external Dictionary.txt file, but I also have an array set up in the code (whitelist).

Please help me out! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the simple way i can imagine it

```
var words:Array = ["test", "fu--"];
//
function dicionary(word:String) {
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i] == word) {
            trace ("####");
        }
    }
}
//
dicionary("fu--");
dicionary("Hello");
```

Hope it helps

**EDITED**

even better like this, because now it can replace words within sentences

```
var words:Array = ["test", "fu--"];
//
function dicionary(word:String) {
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        word = word.split(words[i]).join("####");
    }
    return(word);
}
//
trace(dicionary("fu-- I was wrong!"));
trace(dicionary("Hello"));
```

Comment: Good answer, because I believe it is not practical to be running a word whitelist but instead a word blacklist to determine whether or not a word should be displayed.. Regardless of the OP's intentions, it is incredibly process-heavy to go through an entire list of allowed words as opposed to disallowed words -- is it not?